# How to convert my character vector ( January 2012) to date vector in R

Tags: r, lubridate

This may seem to be pretty easy but I dont know where I'm going wrong. I have a character vector with dates of form `"January 2012", "March 2012"` and so on. I have tried a few different codes but none of them seems to work and returns `NA` values.

Code1:

```
as.POSIXct(df$date, format = "%Y %B")
```

returns `NA` vales

Code2:

```
as_date(df$date, format= NULL)
```

returns  `NA` values and the warning message:

```
Warning message:
All formats failed to parse. No formats found.
```

Code3:

```
as.Date(df$date, "%Y %B")
```

returns  `NA` values and the warning message:

```
Warning message:
In strptime(x, format, tz = "GMT") : unknown timezone 'PLT-3PLT'
```

Comment: Are you set on `lubridate`?  I believe `zoo` allows for year-month date formats, whereas `lubridate` follows the convention that dates must specify a day.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A date needs to include the day of the month. Typically in dealing with month-only data, we would use the first of the month. The solution is therefore to paste a 1 to the front of each string and use the format `"%d %Y %B"` as shown in this reproducible example:

```r
df <- data.frame(date = c('2022 January', '2022 March'))

as.POSIXct(paste(1, df$date), format = "%d %Y %B")
#> [1] "2022-01-01 GMT" "2022-03-01 GMT"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-09-29 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Sorry. Just edited the question its 2012 January format

Comment: @AliInayat OK - updated

Comment: Thanks! done. Was stuck on this for 1 hour. Can you also please tell how to get the format of "2012 january" for viewing as I need to further make a graph using this vector as x-axis

Comment: If your dates are in a vector called `x` you would do `format(x, '%Y %B')`